# MySQL 32 bit or 64 bit - Apache 32 bit Windows 64 bit?

Tags: php, mysql, apache, windows-7, 64-bit

I'm using Windows 7 64 bit.

There is no official 64 bit installer for Apache so I'm using Apache 2.2.22 32 bit (and PHP 5.3.18 32 bit btw).

I suppose I should use MySQL 32 bit then (otherwise there would be conflicts with Apache and/or PHP as I vaguely recall my trials and errors long ago)

Have I missed anything?

Comment: Yes, but there is a a trade off - I've had problems with PHP CURL a few times now

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that MySQL and PHP are linked through socket, so the version of bit doesn't matter in this case.

I'm using nginx x86, PHP x86 and MySQL x64 on my Windows 7 x64, they works well.